# String validation in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate a set of strings and do stuff with it. The acceptable formats are :

```
1/2
12/1/3
1/23/333/4
```

The code used for validation is:

```
if (str.matches("(\\d+\\/|\\d+){2,4}")) {
    // do some stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

But it will match any integer with or without slashes, I want to exclude ones without slashes.. How can I match only the valid patterns?

Comment: Like what "_other cases_"? Give us the cases it matches when it shouldn't.

Comment: Do you need the digits to be consecutive?

Comment: It will match any integer with or without slashes, I want to exclude ones without slashes.

Comment: @BinoyBabu see [Pshemo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo)'s answer then.

Comment: @Mena no, digits need not be consecutive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to find `number` (series of one or more digits - `\d+`) with *one or more* `/number` after it. If that is the case then you can write your regex as

```
\\d+(/\\d+)+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
                                        (\d+/){1,3}\d+
digits followed by / one to three times----^^^^^^   ^^------followed by digit
```

Sample code:

```
System.out.println("1/23/333/4".matches("(\\d+/){1,3}\\d+")); // true
System.out.println("1/2".matches("(\\d+/){1,3}\\d+"));        // true
System.out.println("12/1/3".matches("(\\d+/){1,3}\\d+"));     // true
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1 (between 1 and 3 times):
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
    /                        '/'
  ){1,3}                   end of \1
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\\b\\d+(/\\d+){1, 3}\\b
```

\b is a word boundary.  This will match all tokens with 1-3 slashes, with the slashes surrounded by digits and the token surrounded by word boundaries.